# extract value before a string regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i have a question,  need to extract a value before a defined string, but i can't, for example  need to extract the value "Pudahuel", this word (dinamic) It is before the word "Horario", any suggestions?

```
 Orden de Trabajo
                                                            N° 0200087663


                                                                 Pudahuel Horario Atención: LU a VI de 08:30 a 13:00 y 14:30 a 19:00
Datos de Recepción:
```

example link: https://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/29

Answer (score 1):

Your `(.*)(?=Horario)` matches 0+ chars other than a newline (because you did not use the DOTALL modifier) before a `Horario` text. Note there is a linebreak between the words you need.

Use the following regex

```
(\w+)\s*Horario
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO5yV1/1)

The value you need will be in Group 1. Instead of `\w+` (one or more word chars, those from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` range) you may use `[a-zA-Z]+`, or even `\p{L}+` (any 1+ letters).

**NOTE**: When you have Unicode chars in the patter/string, you need to use the `/u` modifier:

```
/(\w+)\s*Horario/u
```

or [your suggested pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615001/extract-value-before-a-string-regex/38615277?noredirect=1#comment64619718_38615277) (a bit enhanced):

```
/N°\s+(\S+)/u
            ^
```

Comment: bro you rock!!!!!!!! thanks, and if the value is "LA SERENA" instead of "PUDAHUEL" (because the text are dinamic), any idea? :'v

Comment: It depends on the criteria. If you want to match a chunk of space separated ALLCAPS words before `Horario`, use [`\b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+))\s*Horario`](https://regex101.com/r/tO5yV1/2).

Comment: Or, if you need to match the whole string free from the initial whitespace before an `Horario` word that appears at the start of the next line, use [`/^\h*(.*)\R+Horario/m`](https://regex101.com/r/tO5yV1/3).

Comment: thanks!!, now i have a problem with the ordinal character (°), because need to extract the value (0200087663, the number is dinamic), but the cron doesnt recognize the char (°), any idea?

Comment: No idea what input you have. Please note that you may use the last pattern in the previous comment to just match anything. Also, you can always include any chars into character classes. Say, `[\w°]` will match a word char and a `°`.

Comment: /N°(?:\s)(([^\s]+))/ i use this but in php doesnt work, i think are the (°) char.. i'm going insane..

Comment: In PHP, you need `/u` modifier with Unicode strings. See `/^\h*(.*)\R+Horario/mu`, or some variations of your above regex: `/N°\s([^\s]+)/u`, or `/N°\s(\S+)/u`, or `/N°\s+(\S+)/u`.

Comment: I  served your contribution , I am very grateful!!, thanks m'a friend!! mission complete!!!!!!! @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Then please consider accepting the answer (since it is working for you) and upvoting (If it turned out helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Your initial string could contain vertical/horizontal tabs, use the following regexp:

```
(\b[\w ]*?)[\v\h]?(?=Horario)
```

[DEMO link](https://regex101.com/r/pE4sG7/1)

Comment: thanks!!, now i have a problem with the ordinal character (°), because need to extract the value (0200087663, the number is dinamic), but the cron doesnt recognize the char (°), any idea?

Comment: This is a case where one really does not need to use a lookaround.